# Problem to create and run an inteliJ project

Tags: java, maven

I got stucked on following problem:
I use

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1
Spring 3.0.1
JDK 8.0351
java version "1.8.0_351"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_351-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.351-b10, mixed mode)
```

When Creating new project `Eclipse Projects` is shown up to the left

[image: intellij IDEA project type]

I select springboot initializer to create the project using
JDK 1.8.0351 and Java 17 then I get this error message ...`selected Java version not supported`.
[selected Java version not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q91zG.png)

I change to Java 8 -> project created but pom file anyway contains

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

and I get this error when I run.

```
java: warning: source release 17 requires target release 17
Module padelup SDK 1.8 is not compatible with the source version 17.
Upgrade Module SDK in project settings to 17 or higher. Open project settings.
```

I think there is some trash left from old versions of java, intelij, maven dependencies ...
somewhere in the disk, but have no idea how to make a thorough clean up without damaging
used apps/settings

Comment: You try to compile a source-level 17 project with a JDK 8 compiler. This won't work. The reason should be obvious.

Comment: yes, thats obvious, but when I run 8 with 18, it does anyway change to 17 in the pom, <java.version>17</java.version>

Comment: If you use Spring 3.X you have to use JDK17 at minimum. There is no choice to use something less JDK17 that will simply not work. Also you have to configure in IntelliJ to use the same version for the JDK.

Comment: thanks,  now  with jdk 19 and java 17 it works.